# ListAnimate for nested lists with two sliders

Tags: plotting, manipulate, slider

I have a very complicated function of three variables `(a,b,c)`. Now I want to plot the function value as a function of `a` while being able to manipulate `b` and `c`. `Manipulate` does not work well for me as the function takes quiet some time to evaluate. Therefore I had a look at ListAnimate which works nice if I only want to vary one parameter, e.g. for a *simple* example:

```
testList = Table[Plot[a*x^2, {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {0.0, 4.0}], {a, 0.1, 1.0, 0.01}];

ListAnimate[testList]
```

How can I expand this to work for two variables meaning that I want to have two sliders to move through either direction of this matrix of plots.

The following example gives me an animated List instead of two sliders:

```
testList = Table[Plot[a*x^2/x^(b*0.1), {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {0.0, 4.0}], {a, 0.1, 1.0, 0.01}, {b, 1., 10., 1.}];

ListAnimate[testList]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `Manipulate` can still be useful:

```
ClearAll[plot];
Do[
  plot[a, b] = 
   Plot[a*(x - b)^2, {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {0.0, 4.0}}],
  {a, .1, 1.0, 0.1}, {b, 0, 1, .1}];


Manipulate[
 plot[a, b]
 ,
  {a, .1, 1.0, 0.1}, {b, 0., 1, .1}
  ]
```

Keep in mind that the number of frames you want to precalculate is growing fast with number of parameters and resolution.

Comment: Or just `Manipulate[testList[[n, m]], {n, 1, Length@testList, 1}, {m, 1, Length@testList[[1]], 1}]`.

Comment: @Karsten7. yes, I don't know why I went `DownValues` way.

Comment: @Karsten7. oh I know, because in your way you have to convert indices to values if you want to show parameters state. Not a big deal but this way is shorter.